# Is it best practice to use surrogate keys when creating foreign key constraints in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, concurrency, snapshot-isolation

I'm trying my best not to ask a leading question, but after a lot of searching I'm unable to find a similar answer or recommendation.

First, take a look at this question I asked on Stack Overflow last week: [Why does inserting a row with a foreign key referencing a row by pk modified in another snapshot isolation transaction cause the transaction to hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228794/why-does-inserting-a-row-with-a-foreign-key-referencing-a-row-by-pk-modified-in/53229119)

In our database we have 4 tables. *Two* has a foreign key to *One*'s primary clustered key. *Four* has a foreign key to *Three* via a surrogate key. In all cases, the keys are meaningless.

[image: Database diagram with four tables]

Imagine two scenarios:

In a snapshot transaction where a column is modified in *One*, another snapshot transaction begins where a row is simply inserted into *Two*, where the foreign key column has the value of the row being modified in *One*. The latter transaction will block until the former transaction is committed, and then the latter transaction will abort with a snapshot isolation error.

In a very similar situation, a snapshot transaction begins where a column is modified in *Three*, another snapshot transaction begins where a row is simply inserted into *Four*, where the foreign key column has the value of the row being modified in *Three* (via its surrogate key). The latter transaction will finish without issue before the former transaction is committed.

Despite [the answer being rather simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229119/825011), this is unintuitive to me. I almost want to consider this a bug in SQL Server. The first scenario's transaction doesn't have a legitimate reason to block, and it especially doesn't have a legitimate reason to roll back the transaction. It does so basically because of an implementation detail. But if you just use a surrogate foreign key, everything works as expected and nothing is blocked or conflicts.

Is it best practice to use surrogate keys when creating foreign key constraints in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

> Despite the answer being rather simple, this is unintuitive to me. I almost want to consider this a bug in SQL Server. The first scenario's transaction doesn't have a legitimate reason to block, and it especially doesn't have a legitimate reason to roll back the transaction. It does so basically because of an implementation detail. But if you just use a surrogate foreign key, everything works as expected and nothing is blocked or conflicts.

It's not the *surrogate key* aspect that is important, it is whether a key-only **nonclustered** index is used for the foreign key validation, or the key-plus-data **clustered** index.

The SQL Server implementation *always* takes a *shared lock* when validating foreign keys on the parent side, to ensure the *most recent committed* data is read, and stays that way until that row's update is complete.

Under RCSI, this can lead to unexpected **blocking**, as you show. Under SI (snapshot isolation) it can result in an arguably-unnecessary **update conflict** error being reported.

In this case, RCSI blocks but continues after the blocking transaction commits or rolls back. Under SI, the blocked transaction **aborts** with an update conflict if the blocking transaction commits (but succeeds if it rolls back).

The index used to check a foreign key need not be the *primary key*, it can be **any key** for the relation. You may choose to enforce that key with a nonclustered or clustered unique index for a variety of reasons. It is not uncommon for the primary key to be nonclustered, and another candidate key to be clustered.

Snapshot isolation is most appropriate for read-mostly workloads, where update conflicts (real or imagined) will likely be rare.

More information in two of my articles:

- [Foreign Keys, Blocking, and Update Conflicts](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/06/sql-performance/foreign-keys-blocking-update-conflicts) (this specific issue)
- [The SNAPSHOT Isolation Level](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/sql-performance/the-snapshot-isolation-level) (other surprises)